# Why does this NSDateFormatter return nil?

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Why does the following return `nil`?

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd"
let formattedDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString("2016-04-20 06:00:00 +0000")
```

Comment: The date format does not match the string at all.

Comment: You want MM/dd value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get `Date`:  **04/20**

```
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZZ"
    let Date = dateFormatter.dateFromString("2016-04-20 06:00:00 +0000")

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd"
    let newDate  = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(Date!)

    print(newDate)
```